# Wacom Intuos CTL-6100WL connects but doesn't work on Manjaro over bluetooth

Tags: arch-linux, manjaro, bluetooth, wacom

I'm trying to connect Wacom Intuos CTL-6100WL tablet to a Manjaro Linux machine.

Everything works if I connect it via usb cable.

When I connect it via bluetooth, the bluetooth device manager finds the tablet and connects to it. The tablet led stops blinking as if it was connected successfully. But it doesn't work and doesn't show up in mouse configuration utility (I run XFCE). And also I can't find any trace of it in `dmesg` (looked for "hid" or "bluetooth" or "input" or "wacom", case-insensitive).

AFAIK my setup meets the requirements from [libwacom device support list](https://github.com/linuxwacom/input-wacom/wiki/Device-IDs):

- I run kernel version 6.6;
- the latest version of `libwacom` (which is 2.9) is installed.

I even installed dkms and input-wacom-dkms-git, as [Arch Linux wacom manual](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Graphics_tablet#Device_not_recognized_by_the_kernel) suggests, but that didn't help.

I've run out of ideas. What else should I check?

Here are the packages and dmesg output:

```
$ yay -Qs wacom
local/input-wacom-dkms-git 0.49.0.73.ga3ebd21-1
    Latest kernel modules for Wacom tablets (DKMS). Useful if your wacom tablet is not supported upstream yet.
local/libwacom 2.9.0-2
    Library to identify Wacom tablets and their features
local/xf86-input-wacom 1.2.0-1
    X.Org Wacom tablet driver

$ sudo dmesg | grep -i -e "wacom\|bluetooth\|input\|hid"
[    0.108508] AMD-Vi: ivrs, add hid:AMDI0020, uid:\_SB.FUR0, rdevid:160
[    0.108510] AMD-Vi: ivrs, add hid:AMDI0020, uid:\_SB.FUR1, rdevid:160
[    0.108510] AMD-Vi: ivrs, add hid:AMDI0020, uid:\_SB.FUR2, rdevid:160
[    0.108511] AMD-Vi: ivrs, add hid:AMDI0020, uid:\_SB.FUR3, rdevid:160
[    0.737964] input: Power Button as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0C:00/input/input0
[    0.738016] input: Lid Switch as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0D:00/input/input1
[    0.740599] input: Power Button as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input2
[    0.790123] hid: raw HID events driver (C) Jiri Kosina
[    1.244538] input: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard as /devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input3
[    1.744434] input:   Mouse for Windows as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:74:00.3/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.0/0003:2F24:0135.0001/input/input4
[    1.744559] hid-generic 0003:2F24:0135.0001: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [  Mouse for Windows] on usb-0000:74:00.3-4/input0
[    1.749428] input:   Mouse for Windows as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:74:00.3/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.1/0003:2F24:0135.0002/input/input5
[    1.804045] hid-generic 0003:2F24:0135.0002: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [  Mouse for Windows] on usb-0000:74:00.3-4/input1
[    1.807564] hid-generic 0003:2F24:0135.0003: hiddev96,hidraw2: USB HID v1.10 Device [  Mouse for Windows] on usb-0000:74:00.3-4/input2
[    1.807599] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[    1.807601] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[    2.386006] input: RODE Microphones RODE NT-USB Consumer Control as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.3/0000:75:00.3/usb7/7-1/7-1.2/7-1.2:1.3/0003:19F7:0003.0004/input/input6
[    2.441016] hid-generic 0003:19F7:0003.0004: input,hiddev97,hidraw3: USB HID v1.00 Device [RODE Microphones RODE NT-USB] on usb-0000:75:00.3-1.2/input3
[    3.858190] input: ZSA Technology Labs Moonlander Mark I as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.3/0000:75:00.3/usb7/7-1/7-1.3/7-1.3.3/7-1.3.3:1.0/0003:3297:1969.0005/input/input8
[    3.914416] hid-generic 0003:3297:1969.0005: input,hidraw4: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [ZSA Technology Labs Moonlander Mark I] on usb-0000:75:00.3-1.3.3/input0
[    3.919360] hid-generic 0003:3297:1969.0006: hiddev98,hidraw5: USB HID v1.11 Device [ZSA Technology Labs Moonlander Mark I] on usb-0000:75:00.3-1.3.3/input1
[    3.924233] input: ZSA Technology Labs Moonlander Mark I as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.3/0000:75:00.3/usb7/7-1/7-1.3/7-1.3.3/7-1.3.3:1.2/0003:3297:1969.0007/input/input9
[    3.924509] hid-generic 0003:3297:1969.0007: input,hidraw6: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [ZSA Technology Labs Moonlander Mark I] on usb-0000:75:00.3-1.3.3/input2
[    3.929195] input: ZSA Technology Labs Moonlander Mark I System Control as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.3/0000:75:00.3/usb7/7-1/7-1.3/7-1.3.3/7-1.3.3:1.3/0003:3297:1969.0008/input/input10
[    3.984063] input: ZSA Technology Labs Moonlander Mark I Consumer Control as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.3/0000:75:00.3/usb7/7-1/7-1.3/7-1.3.3/7-1.3.3:1.3/0003:3297:1969.0008/input/input11
[    3.984270] input: ZSA Technology Labs Moonlander Mark I Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.3/0000:75:00.3/usb7/7-1/7-1.3/7-1.3.3/7-1.3.3:1.3/0003:3297:1969.0008/input/input12
[    3.984724] hid-generic 0003:3297:1969.0008: input,hidraw7: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [ZSA Technology Labs Moonlander Mark I] on usb-0000:75:00.3-1.3.3/input3
[    7.886776] input: Video Bus as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/device:1e/LNXVIDEO:00/input/input13
[    7.909964] input: PC Speaker as /devices/platform/pcspkr/input/input14
[    8.043082] input: PNP0C50:00 093A:0255 Mouse as /devices/platform/AMDI0010:00/i2c-0/i2c-PNP0C50:00/0018:093A:0255.0009/input/input15
[    8.043213] input: PNP0C50:00 093A:0255 Touchpad as /devices/platform/AMDI0010:00/i2c-0/i2c-PNP0C50:00/0018:093A:0255.0009/input/input16
[    8.043328] hid-generic 0018:093A:0255.0009: input,hidraw8: I2C HID v1.00 Mouse [PNP0C50:00 093A:0255] on i2c-PNP0C50:00
[    8.111646] input: GXTP7385:00 27C6:0113 as /devices/platform/AMDI0010:01/i2c-1/i2c-GXTP7385:00/0018:27C6:0113.000A/input/input17
[    8.127378] input: GXTP7385:00 27C6:0113 Stylus as /devices/platform/AMDI0010:01/i2c-1/i2c-GXTP7385:00/0018:27C6:0113.000A/input/input18
[    8.160965] input: GXTP7385:00 27C6:0113 UNKNOWN as /devices/platform/AMDI0010:01/i2c-1/i2c-GXTP7385:00/0018:27C6:0113.000A/input/input19
[    8.161153] input: GXTP7385:00 27C6:0113 Keyboard as /devices/platform/AMDI0010:01/i2c-1/i2c-GXTP7385:00/0018:27C6:0113.000A/input/input20
[    8.161315] hid-multitouch 0018:27C6:0113.000A: input,hidraw8: I2C HID v1.00 Keyboard [GXTP7385:00 27C6:0113] on i2c-GXTP7385:00
[    8.169622] input: PNP0C50:00 093A:0255 Mouse as /devices/platform/AMDI0010:00/i2c-0/i2c-PNP0C50:00/0018:093A:0255.0009/input/input21
[    8.169715] input: PNP0C50:00 093A:0255 Touchpad as /devices/platform/AMDI0010:00/i2c-0/i2c-PNP0C50:00/0018:093A:0255.0009/input/input22
[    8.169828] hid-multitouch 0018:093A:0255.0009: input,hidraw9: I2C HID v1.00 Mouse [PNP0C50:00 093A:0255] on i2c-PNP0C50:00
[    8.341344] input: HD-Audio Generic HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:74:00.1/sound/card0/input23
[    8.342769] input: HD-Audio Generic HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:74:00.1/sound/card0/input24
[    8.342859] input: HD-Audio Generic HDMI/DP,pcm=8 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:74:00.1/sound/card0/input25
[    8.342975] input: HD-Audio Generic HDMI/DP,pcm=9 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:74:00.1/sound/card0/input26
[    8.409879] snd_hda_codec_conexant hdaudioC1D0:    inputs:
[    8.450787] input: HD-Audio Generic Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:74:00.6/sound/card1/input27
[    8.452959] input: HD-Audio Generic Headphone as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:74:00.6/sound/card1/input28
[   10.038253] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   10.038281] NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family
[   10.038282] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   10.038291] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   10.038294] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   10.038298] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   10.193343] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware timestamp 2023.42 buildtype 1 build 73111
[   10.193356] Bluetooth: hci0: No support for _PRR ACPI method
[   10.200880] Bluetooth: hci0: Found device firmware: intel/ibt-0041-0041.sfi
[   10.200900] Bluetooth: hci0: Boot Address: 0x100800
[   10.200902] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware Version: 151-42.23
[   10.200904] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware already loaded
[   10.464137] Modules linked in: r8152(+) mii uvcvideo btusb videobuf2_vmalloc btrtl uvc btintel videobuf2_memops snd_soc_dmic videobuf2_v4l2 btbcm snd_usb_audio(+) snd_soc_acp6x_mach snd_acp6x_pdm_dma btmtk snd_sof_amd_vangogh videodev snd_sof_amd_rembrandt snd_usbmidi_lib bluetooth snd_sof_amd_renoir snd_ump snd_rawmidi videobuf2_common snd_sof_amd_acp snd_seq_device mc ecdh_generic snd_sof_pci iwlmvm snd_sof_xtensa_dsp intel_rapl_msr amdgpu(+) intel_rapl_common snd_sof snd_hda_codec_conexant snd_sof_utils mac80211 snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio snd_soc_core snd_hda_codec_hdmi libarc4 snd_compress ac97_bus snd_hda_intel drm_exec snd_pcm_dmaengine snd_intel_dspcfg amdxcp snd_intel_sdw_acpi snd_pci_ps drm_buddy edac_mce_amd snd_hda_codec snd_rpl_pci_acp6x gpu_sched iwlwifi snd_acp_pci i2c_algo_bit snd_hda_core kvm_amd snd_acp_legacy_common drm_suballoc_helper snd_pci_acp6x drm_ttm_helper snd_hwdep snd_pcm snd_pci_acp5x ttm kvm cfg80211 snd_timer snd_rn_pci_acp3x mousedev joydev drm_display_helper snd_acp_config snd
[   10.464251]  irqbypass sp5100_tco vfat cec snd_soc_acpi hid_multitouch fat rapl pcspkr thunderbolt i2c_piix4 snd_pci_acp3x k10temp soundcore video rfkill i2c_hid_acpi wmi i2c_hid acpi_tad mac_hid uinput crypto_user loop fuse nfnetlink bpf_preload ip_tables x_tables ext4 crc32c_generic crc16 mbcache jbd2 uas usb_storage usbhid dm_crypt cbc encrypted_keys trusted asn1_encoder tee dm_mod crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul crc32c_intel polyval_clmulni polyval_generic gf128mul ghash_clmulni_intel serio_raw sha512_ssse3 atkbd sha256_ssse3 libps2 sha1_ssse3 aesni_intel vivaldi_fmap nvme crypto_simd cryptd nvme_core xhci_pci i8042 ccp xhci_pci_renesas nvme_common serio
[   21.469750] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   21.469754] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   21.469758] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   21.470761] Bluetooth: MGMT ver 1.22
[   21.921439] Bluetooth: hci0: Bad flag given (0x1) vs supported (0x0)
[  153.645923] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[  153.645937] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[  153.645944] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[  162.966924] input: BT5.0 Mouse as /devices/virtual/misc/uhid/0005:000E:3412.000B/input/input29
[  162.967068] hid-generic 0005:000E:3412.000B: input,hidraw10: BLUETOOTH HID v5.06 Mouse [BT5.0 Mouse] on 74:04:f1:33:c4:e8
[  204.725251] Bluetooth: HIDP (Human Interface Emulation) ver 1.2
[  204.725259] Bluetooth: HIDP socket layer initialized
```

Here are tablet parameters from `bluetoothctm`:

```
Device E0:9F:2A:23:E0:F5 (public)
    Name: Intuos BT M
    Alias: Intuos BT M
    Class: 0x00002594 (9620)
    Icon: input-tablet
    Paired: yes
    Bonded: no
    Trusted: yes
    Blocked: no
    Connected: yes
    WakeAllowed: yes
    LegacyPairing: no
    UUID: Human Interface Device... (00001124-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: PnP Information           (00001200-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    Modalias: usb:v056Ap0379d0000
```